# Input a string to application without pasteboard or simulating typing

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, pasteboard

I need to paste a string of text to whichever application is open, and I'd rather not clear the pasteboard, in case something important is there, and I'd rather not turn every single character into a keyboard event.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using accessibility: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Accessibility/cocoaAXIntro/cocoaAXintro.html
though it may be overkill.

Another option may be to copy the current contents of the pasteboard to a local variable, replace it with your own string, perform your paste, then restore the original value back to the pasteboard.  Depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks. That's also what I was thinking about copying the contents and putting back afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You could provide a [service](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/introduction.html) to paste the provided text.